# PyEphem - illuminated fraction of the Moon calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyephem

How can I calculate the illuminated fraction of the Moon using Python3 ?

```
Date = datetime.date.today()
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? Usually Stackoverflow is here to help you, when you hit a roadblock, not to write complete programs for you.

Comment: The website of PyEphem refers to Stackoverflow, so that's why I ended up here.  When I use PyEphem, moon_phase does not seem to work, that's why I asked it in general terms.

Comment: Give us the code in question and the exception/error it throws, otherwise it's hard to help.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I have found the answer :

import datetime

import ephem

date = datetime.date.today()

m = ephem.Moon(date)

print(m.moon_phase)